# Increase a value in Manipulation automatically without cycling

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I am looking for a function in Manipulation block that enables me to increase a value, say t, automatically when a certain condition is reached, say x>=5. I realize Clock can increase t but it cycles automatically which I don't really want. Thanks for the help!

Oscar

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need. From the description above it would seems that a simple if, something like If[x>=5, t=t+1] would work. Can you place your question into more context?

Comment: Oh, sorry about the unclearness. I use Trigger to increase x automatically from 0 to 10 once being clicked, and when it reaches 5, I want to increase t from 0 to 1 automatically and monotonically with time, without recycling again to 0. t is in the body of Manipulation. Is that possible? Thanks Bill.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? This would help figure out how to fix it.

Comment: To trigger x I use Control[{ {x, 0}, 0, 10, Trigger }]; to control t I use t  = If[ x<5, 0, Dynamic[Clock[{0,1,0.1},2]]]. Now I've achieved that once x is larger than 5, t will change from 0 to 1, but it cycles. I just want to let t increase from 0 to 1 once without cycling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any code so not certain how close this applies.  However, you can use the [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) syntax of [`Dynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) to control an [`Animator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animator.html) from your [`Trigger`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trigger.html).

With

```
x = 0;
t = 0;
runt = False;
```

Then

```
{
  {
   Trigger[
    Dynamic[x, {None, Automatic, (x = #; If[# >= 5, runt = True]; &)}],
    {0, 10},
    AppearanceElements -> {"PlayButton", "PauseButton", "ResetButton"}],
   Dynamic[x]
   },
  {
   Animator[Dynamic[t],
    AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[runt, TrackedSymbols :> {x}],
    AnimationRepetitions -> 1,
    AnimationRate -> 0.1,
    AppearanceElements -> {"PlayButton", "PauseButton", "ResetButton"}],
   Dynamic[t]
  }
} // Grid
```

Comment: Thanks Edmund! This code helps a lot. One question is that, after running one time, I click the reset button of both lines and then click the play button of the first line, then when the number of first line reaches 5, the number at the second line will start from a nonzero number. Is there an method that enable it to starts from 0 after resetting for both lines? Thanks!

Comment: @Oscar Not restarting at zero after reset may be a bug. Report to WRI and see what they have to say.